# Update is telling me my package system is broken - the instruction to fix it doesn't work - what to do?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, dpkg

I am using Linux Mint 12 and currently have the Mate desktop running. The icon in the upper right showed their were updates. Tried to do it and it said that

> The package system is broken
>
> Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them,
>   since they are a common source of problems. Furthermore run the
>   following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

The details are:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>
> mint-artwork-gnome: Depends: gtk2-engines-clearlooks but it is a
>   virtual package
>                       Depends: mint-backgrounds-lisa but it is not installed

sudo apt-get install -f gives this output:

> Reading package lists... Done 
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>
> Correcting dependencies... Done
>
> The following extra packages will be installed:
>      mint-backgrounds-lisa
>   The following NEW packages will be installed:
>      mint-backgrounds-lisa
>   0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 32 not upgraded. 
>   4 not fully installed or removed. 
>   Need to get 0 B/3,003 kB of archives.
>   After this operation, 3,265 kB of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y 
>   (Reading database ... 482703 files and directories currently installed.) 
>   Unpacking mint-backgrounds-lisa (from .../mint-backgrounds-lisa_1.1_all.deb) ... 
>   dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/mint-backgrounds-lisa_1.1_all.deb (--unpack):
>    trying to overwrite '/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/linuxmint-lisa.xml', which is also in package mint-artwork-kde 2.0.1 
>   dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    /var/cache/apt/archives/mint-backgrounds-lisa_1.1_all.deb
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

If I try and install the latest version of Chromium by double-clicking the deb file is says:

> gdebi-gtk Broken Dependencies
>
> Your system has broken dependencies. This application cannot continue
>   until this is fixed. To fix it run 'gksudo synaptic' or 'sudo apt-get
>   install -f' in a terminal window.

If I run 'gksudo synaptic' Synaptic comes up and says:

> (as superuser) You have 1 broken package on your system!
>
> Use the "Broken" filter to locate it.

The Broken filter shows:

> Synaptic Broken       Installed Version   Latest Version    Description
>   mint-artwork-gnome    2.6.20              2.6.20           Default Artwork for Linux Mint

Trying to reinstall the above package gives:

An error occurred
The following details are provided:

> E: /var/cache/apt/archives/mint-backgrounds-lisa_1.1_all.deb: trying
>   to overwrite
>   '/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/linuxmint-lisa.xml', which is
>   also in package mint-artwork-kde 2.0.1

One easy solution is probably to not run Mate with Linux Mint (this is my first try), but just wondering if this is fixable.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A quick and dirty fix, was hack the dpkg records,

Since `/usr/share/gnome-background-properties/linuxmint-lisa.xml` belongs two packages, you're going to remove it from one,

Goto `/var/lib/dpkg/info/mint-artwork-kde.list`, remove that xml filename from the file.

And redo `apt-get -f install`

Notice in the future this package conflicts will be solved by the packager (let's hope), and later updates will not be affected.

Comment: I deleted this line /usr/share/gnome-background-properties/linuxmint-lisa.xml
 from this file /var/lib/dpkg/info/mint-artwork-kde.list . However, apt-get install -f is still not happy and still complaining about lisa. EDIT: I removed all the lines with lisa in them and now install -f gives a different error, in fact it refers to it as a Traceback. Guess Mate and KDE don't play well together. Or Mate and Mint.

Comment: Tampering with the dpkg records is never a good idea. This issue is better fixed through the available tools in the package system. Manually editing the records may cause even worse problems.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to manually hacking `dpkg` data files is to use the `--force-overwrite` option to `dpkg`, e.g.,

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/mint-backgrounds-lisa_1.1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try as hard as you can **not** to meddle with the package system by manually removing files from packages or forcing things through `dpkg`. This usually tends to break the system even further and makes recovery even more difficult.

Broken packages are usually the result of a problem with your repositories: there is either an unresolved conflict between two packages (and in this case one of the packages has a problem or has been tampered with), or a dependency for a package you want to install is not available (although the repository information claims it is).

Also, there seems to be some confusion as to which package has the problem: it is not `mint-backgrounds-lisa` but `mint-artwork-kde`. My suggestion to you is to remove the offending package:

> `# dpkg -P mint-artwork-kde`

and then try to run:

> `# apt-get -f install`

so apt can work out the issues and solve the problem by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands as root

```
sudo apt-get purge mint-backgrounds-lisa && sudo apt-get install mint-backgrounds-lisa 
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

If this doesn't address problem please paste output.

Comment: I use ~> to represent the command prompt, is this improper format?